# Центрирование JButton

Tags: java

Каким образом можно центрировать JButton? Делают вот так, ничего не получается:

```
import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.*;

    class GraphTest {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Hello!");
            frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            panel.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

            JButton button = new JButton("Click me!");
            button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 50));

            panel.add(button);
            frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER); //не работает
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class GraphTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(" Hello!");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        Container c = frame.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JButton button = new JButton("Кнопка");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
        panel.add(button, gbc);
        c.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```